# Can't find migration biosphere-2-3-categories

Tags: brightway

I import an Excel database:

```
imp = bw.ExcelImporter(os.path.join("myfile.xls"))
```

And then apply strategies to it:

```
imp.apply_strategies()
```

But this issue arises:

```
AssertionError: Can't find migration biosphere-2-3-categories
```

I would like to understand what's happening and actually what is this "migration biosphere 2-3"?
My exchanges in my excel file concern only biosphere-3... but I suppose it doesn't have much to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the function [`bw2io.bw2setup`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/legacy/bw2io/__init__.py#L111) calls the function [`bw2io.migrations.create_core_migrations`](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/72544e14addcd39204f7ff5a6b7b4b829899284e/bw2io/migrations.py#L58), which installs sets of metadata to translate from one nomenclature system to another. If you can't find this migration data, then you need to import and call `create_core_migrations`.

You can see the actual changes in the names of elementary flow categories from [ecoinvent version 2 to version 3 here](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/72544e14addcd39204f7ff5a6b7b4b829899284e/bw2io/compatibility.py#L39).

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question: what do you mean by "import" this migration data?